# command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync() thorws error: 'BeginExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a function that executes a stored procedure:

```
public async Task RunFinanceSummaryAggregationAsync()
{

    connection ??= dBcontext.Database.GetDbConnection();
    using var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "sp_FinanceSummaryAggregation";

    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        await connection.OpenAsync();

    await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
```

}

This function is called by an Azure Service bus. For that I have a message object and a message handler.

```
public record DrawCompletedMessage() : IMessage
{
}

public class DrawCompletedMessageHandler : IMessageHandler<DrawCompletedMessage>
{
    private readonly IReportService reportService;

    private readonly ILogger<DrawCompletedMessageHandler> logger;

    public DrawCompletedMessageHandler(IReportService reportService, ILogger<DrawCompletedMessageHandler> logger)
    {
        this.reportService = reportService;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task HandleAsync(DrawCompletedMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await reportService.RunFinanceSummaryAggregationAsync();
    }
}
```

The queue is registered on WebApplicationBuilder:

```
public static void Configure(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.AddMessaging().AddServiceBus(serviceBus =>
    {
        var drawCompletedQueue = builder.Configuration.GetQueueConfiguration("DrawCompletedQueue");

        serviceBus.AddNamespace(drawCompletedQueue.Namespace, drawCompletedQueue.ConnectionString);

        serviceBus.AddQueue(drawCompletedQueue.Namespace, drawCompletedQueue.QueueName, q =>
        {
            q.AddMessage<DrawCompletedMessage, DrawCompletedMessageHandler>();
        });
    });
}
```

The RunFinanceSummaryAggregationAsync is get called, and when executes the line:

```
await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
```

it throws an error:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'BeginExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized.'

In my stored procedure I don't have a transaction it has a marge table or update table command.

thnx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please, don does not comment answers like this.

Comment: Have you tried moving everything command related behind (after) the check and possible opening of the connection?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.
Might help someone.

```
var executionStrategy = dBcontext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
await executionStrategy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
{ 
    using var transaction = await dBcontext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
    try
    {
        using var connection = new SqlConnection(dBcontext.Database.GetConnectionString());

        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            await connection.OpenAsync();

        var command = new SqlCommand("exec sp_FinanceSummaryAggregation", connection);
        await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        await transaction.RollbackAsync();
    }
});
```